# Order Json object

Tags: json, angular, http, get

I'm creating a simple movie listing app with Angular 4. I'm making an HTTP GET request to fetch all the movies stored in a json file. They have some fields like "Id", "Title", "Genre", "Duration", etc. When i'm listing all the movies, how can i order them by ID descending, so that the last one appear first?

Here's the code that i am using to get this json data:

On my data service file:

```
getMovies(){
      return this.http.get('assets/data/movies.json')
      .map(res => res.json());
   }
```

On my component.ts file:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: Movies[];
  username:string;
  userimg:string;

  constructor(private userService:UserService, private dataService:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.getMovies().subscribe((movies) =>{
        this.movies = movies;
    });


  }


}

interface Movies {
    id:number,
    title:string,
    year:number,
    rating:number,
    cover:string,
    genre:string,
    duration:string,
    description:string,
    favourite:number
}
```

On my component.html file:

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies" class="row row-movies">
              <a [routerLink]="['/movies', {'id': movie.id}]">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h3> {{movie.title}}</h3>
                    <h4> {{movie.year}}</h4>
                    <h4> {{movie.rating}}</h4>
                    <p>{{movie.description}}</p>
                    <h5> {{movie.genre}}</h5>
                    <h5> {{movie.duration}}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <img src="../assets/img/capas/movies/{{movie.capa}}" class="img-responsive capa-filme" width="350px" />
                </div>
              </a>
      </div>
```

Can you help me please? I'm still very noob with Angular..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with angular. You need to do, after loading the movies, something like this:

```
this.movies.sort((a,b) => (b.id - a.id));
```

As a note: this works using any Array in vanilla javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the sort to change, you can do it as you retrieve the data.

```
this.dataService.getMovies().subscribe((movies) =>{
        movies.sort((a, b) => {
           return a.id < b.id ? 1 : -1;
     });
     this.movies = movies;
 });
```

NOTE: I did not syntax check this.